# window.open ignores (with firefox & safari) specified height and width when parent window is maximized

Tags: javascript, html, ubuntu, firefox, wayland

I'm tryng to make my js code open popup, with specified position, height and width.

```
let windowFeatures = "left=100,top=100,width=800,height=600"
window.open('img.html', 'foobar', windowFeatures);
```

On Ubuntu 22.04, with Firefox (105.0.2), the position & dimensions stuff only works when my browser window is not maximized. If the parent window is maximized, the popup will also be maximized...
Same problem with safari on macOS.

I don't have the problem with chromium (106 on ubuntu), even when maximized.

any known workaround ?

Comment: Safari on macOS can't be "maximised", I think you mean full screen mode and you can't break out of that with JS.

Comment: don't know much about the macOS stuff... Sorry about my lack of terminology. Anyway, the problem occurs on ubuntu with maximized windows (not talking about the F11 fullscreen feature)

Comment: _"I'm tryng to make my js code open popup, with specified position, height and width."_ - why, is it still 2004? Modern browsers give the user a lot more control over stuff like this. Mine for example is configured to not ever even open any actual "popups", but only new full-sized tabs. Unless you want this for one specific environment that you are in full control of, I'd say - forget it.

Comment: Me too... and... what's your point? I have to install open source web analytics applications for my work even though I have a tracker blocker installed on my computer.  Your needs are not my needs and they are not the needs of my clients either. We have researchers here who need web applications on multiple windows that communicate with each other, applications that are resizable, and moveable across multiple screens.